# Defining Typescript module typings on separate file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have project with a few components containing a large set of types and interfaces.
For example, `src/components/MyComponent.tsx`. The problem is that those typings are usually making the file difficult to read and follow along the logic implemented.

With that in mind, I was wondering what would be the best way to have the typings for those components defined on a separate file, like `src/types/MyComponent.d.ts`?

I've tried declaring a module like:

```
declare module '../components/MyComponent' {
   type Foo = string;
}
```

But the problem is that I cannot define relative paths to ambient module declarations, and I am not certain having a `///<reference path="../types/MyComponent.d.ts"/>` is still a valid approach, whereas `import {Foo} from '../types/Mycomponent'` inside `src/components/MyComponent.tsx` feels a bit strange as they should be automatically inferred?

Comment: You should define your interfaces in separate files, possibly in a separate, dedicated folder for interfaces/models. You can then import the necessary interfaces from within your components. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Hi, @MikeS. Thanks for your comment. Yes, that is indeed what I am asking. My only conflict here would be having to declaratively import types that are directly related to that component instead of having them available by default? Sometimes they may be model-related as you suggested, in which case, it shouldn't be an issue. But often those are also related to the component itself, where it doesn't feel too intuitive having to import those types? like `import type {Component} from '../types/Component', const component:Component = {}; export default component;`